# how can delete parent bean with its children object using redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have a table named `Child` that has a **Foreign key** from `Parent` table. Now, I need to delete a parent row with its children completely. I use this code in `redbeanphp`:

```
R::trash(parent);
```

But it throws constraint exception because of reference in child table.
how can I delete a bean with its children in one step?

Comment: in `child` table use `on delete casecade` option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want this behavior to be out-of-the-box, you can define the foreign key to do so. In MySQL, this would be done with `ON DELETE CASCADE` when defining the foreign key. [Here's the documentation.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

If you want it to be done on the PHP side, you'd have to do it manually;

```
R::exec('DELETE FROM child_table WHERE parent_id = :pid', array('pid' => $parent->id));
```

(there might be a more "bean" way to do this, I haven't really gotten into it though)

Comment: i was aware about on delete cascade but i would to know abut ability of redbeanphp around this topic. however with on delete cascade it is not necessary